# Stderr redirection doesn't work

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stderr

I'm attempting to redirect stderr from a mbuffer command to a file. It isn't working; the stderr output still appears on the screen and errors.txt is empty. My command is below:

```
$ raspivid -w 1280 -h 720 -o - | mbuffer -m 60M -f -o /tmp/temp_video.h264 2> errors.txt &
[2] 5278
in @ 1006 KiB/s, out @ 1006 KiB/s, 9292 KiB total, buffer   0% full^C
in @  0.0 KiB/s, out @  0.0 KiB/s,  9.9 MiB total, buffer  17% full^C
```

FYI, the stderr output I'm trying to redirect is "in @ 1006 KB/s...."

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try `2>&1` instead of `2>1`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not trying to redirect stdout, only stderror. I'm currently doing 2> errors.txt. It should be 2>&1 errors.txt?

Comment: It looks like mbuffer might be thinking the redirect command is a mbuffer argument..?

Comment: well, you might try prepending `--` before `2>` then. It's an options end delimiter that works with most of CLI tools. Let me know whether it helps.

Comment: It says "mbuffer: fatal: unknown option "--"" if I do mbuffer -t -m 80M -f -o /tmp/temp_video.h264 -- 2>&1 test.txt &

Comment: I don't know if this gives any clues, but mbuffer itself has a param that lets you direct stderr to a file (-l): http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html and even when I try that param, it continues to print stderr to the command line and the file, while it does get created, remains empty.

Comment: Yep, I just revised a man page. Try combining `-o` with `-q`. The later option should prevent splitting stderr output to a console. Tough I doubt it would to the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56282/discussion-between-user2989813-and-ddnomad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong, `mbuffer` [reopens `/dev/tty` if it can't read from its standard error](https://sources.debian.net/src/mbuffer/20161115-1/mbuffer.c/#L2401), defeating your redirection.

You can use the `-q` option to disable the status output. According to the documentation, you could use `-l` to log the status to a file with

```
mbuffer -m 60M -f -o /tmp/temp_video.h264 -l errors.txt &
```

but the status log is buggy: [it always goes to standard error](https://sources.debian.net/src/mbuffer/20161115-1/mbuffer.c/#L472), not the log.

Here's how to fix this.

1. Download the package source

   ```
   apt-get source mbuffer
   ```
2. Add a patch (this requires the `quilt` package)

   ```
   cd mbuffer-20161115
   quilt new 13-status-log.patch
   quilt add mbuffer.c
   ```
3. Edit `mbuffer.c`, and change line 461 (in Debian 8) or 472 (in Debian 9) to

   ```
   nw = write(Log,buf,strlen(buf));
   ```
4. Store the patch

   ```
   quilt refresh
   ```
5. Rebuild the package (this requires the `dpkg-dev` and `devscripts` packages)

   ```
   dch -n "Fix the status log to honour the -l option."
   dch -r ignored
   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
   ```

   (if `dpkg-buildpackage` complains about missing dependencies, install them and try again)
6. Install the updated package

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ../mbuffer_*-?.1_*.deb
   ```

Comment: This patch worked like a charm. I can confirm that this one-line change fixes the issue that -l wasn't logging any statuses.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of mbuffer, and just want to point out that the status log is not buggy. The intention was always to avoid logging status messages to the log, as it spoils the log and makes it unreadable, unless the user explicitly asks for it.

This is done, by raising the verbosity to level 4 with "-v 4".

As the default behavior causes confusion and there is also the option -Q to suppress status messages in the log, I am considering to include status messages in the log in a future release also at verbosity level 3.

Regards,

Thomas